# Converter sql em query builder - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent, querybuilder

Estou iniciando no Laravel e tenho dúvidas em relação ao `eloquent`. Alguém poderia me ajudar a converter esse código `SQL` em `eloquent`?

```
SELECT COUNT(d.id) as total, d.nome_disciplina FROM bd_assuntos as a INNER 
JOIN bd_disciplinas as d on d.id = a.id_disciplina GROUP BY d.id
```

```php
$count_disciplina = DB::table('bd_assuntos as t')
    ->select('count() as total', 'd.nome_disciplina', 't.nome_assunto')
    ->join('bd_disciplinas as d', 't.id_disciplina', '=', 'd.id')
    ->orderBy('d.id') ->get();
```

Comment: Gleyson, seja bem vindo ao Stackoverflow PT, por favor faça um [tour] pela plataforma para entender como ela funciona e como formular suas perguntas.

Comment: Por favor, coloque no seu post o código que você já tentou fazer e o porque não deu certo, sua pergunta esta parecendo mais um "façam para mim" do que um "tire uma duvida", a propósito, você já entrou na documentação do Laravel? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries

Comment: Sim, já fui na documentação e vários vídeos e cursos, porém essa parte tem me tirado do sério.

Comment: $count_disciplina = DB::table('bd_assuntos as t')
                    ->select('count() as total', 'd.nome_disciplina', 't.nome_assunto')
                    ->join('bd_disciplinas as d', 't.id_disciplina', '=', 'd.id')
                    ->orderBy('d.id')
                    ->get();

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o selectRaw no lugar de select, e adicionar a cláusula groupBy com métodos eloquent.

Acredito que um dos erros de retorno que está recebendo é do próprio database, indicando que os campos nome_disciplina e nome_assunto não fazem parte de uma agregação.

```php
$count_disciplina = DB::table('bd_assuntos as t')
    ->selectRaw('count() as total', 'd.nome_disciplina', 't.nome_assunto')
    ->join('bd_disciplinas as d', 't.id_disciplina', '=', 'd.id')
    ->groupBy('d.nome_disciplina')
    ->groupBy('t.nome_assunto')
    ->orderBy('d.id') ->get();
```

Answer (score -3):

Verifique se essa solução resolve seu problema

DB::table("bd_assuntos as a")
->innerJoin("bd_disciplinas as d", function($join){
$join->on("d.id", "=", "a.id_disciplina");
})
->select("count (d.id) as total", "d.nome_disciplina")
->groupBy("d.id")
->get();